# How to use Xcode with C++17

Tags: c++, xcode, c++17

Recently Xcode 9.3 was released. If have been looking forward to this update because I’ve heard it will come up with C++17 support.

But now it appears to me it’s still using C++14. Is it possible to setup Xcode to use C++17 ?

Comment: Xcode 9 is clang 4 based.  Try C++1z.  It will be far from complete support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable C++17 in Xcode for Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288230/how-to-enable-c17-in-xcode-for-mac-osx)