# How do I enable C++17 in Xcode for Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++17, macos-high-sierra, xcode9.4

How do I enable C++17 in Xcode (9.4.1) on OSX High Sierra (10.13.5)?

Comment: What is the question?  This look like an answer

Comment: @claytonjwong This is a very nice answer, but incorrect format. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for more info on how to correctly put something like this on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Hi, I'm new here, I just posted this info, since I thought it would be helpful.  Thanks for sharing the article for the proper format!

Comment: Looks like it might be too late to modify the original post.  Next time I'll make a Jeopardy style question and answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @claytonjwong you should still be able to edit the post? Just click the edit button just above the comments

Comment: I've deleted the answer for you, you should be able to copy and paste the original post from the edit history into a new answer, click the "source" button to get to the original markup

Comment: Thanks @AlanBirtles!

Answer (score 34):

**Steps to use C++17 in Xcode (9.4.1) on OSX High Sierra (10.13.5):**

1. Open existing or create a new C++ project in Xcode
2. Click on the "show project navigator" button.  It is located on the top-left section of Xcode window just below the minimize/maximize/close window buttons.  It is the left-most icon and looks like a folder.
3. Click on "Build Settings" and scroll down to find and expand the section "Apple LLVM 9.0 - Language - C++"
4. Change the C++ Language Dialect combobox selection to "C++17 [-std=c++17]"

[image: Xcode Build Settings]

**Verification steps:**

Now when I output __cplusplus, I see 201703, and I am able to compile C++17 features, such as if constexpr.

```
template<class T>
int compute(T x) {
    if constexpr( supportsAPI(T{}) ) {
        // only gets compiled if the condition is true
        return x.Method();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(){
    cout << __cplusplus << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
201703
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: FWIW, this setting was under `Apple Clang - Language - C++` instead of `Apple LLVM 9.0 - Language - C++` for me - OSX 10.15.6, Xcode version 11.7.

Answer (score 5):

When using development CocoaPods (writing a C++ library) I had also to update `podspec` of this library containing c++ 17 code to make compile host application which included this pod.

So I added these flags to library's `podspec`

```
  spec.xcconfig = { 
    "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++17",
    "CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" => "libc++"
  }
```