# Listing files in a directory in Xcode (macOS)

Tags: c++

I want to list all the txt files in my "Derived Data" Folder, but so far the only thing that I can find that works for macOS is glob.h which I have placed like this, that just outputs the pathname I put in.

```
glob_t glob_result;
    glob("/Users/me/Desktop/XJ/DerivedData", GLOB_TILDE,NULL,&glob_result);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<glob_result.gl_pathc; ++i){
        cout << glob_result.gl_pathv[i] << endl;
```

The boost/filesystem thing doesn't seem to work. Although it might be because of mac pathname styles. Is there any easier way to view all the files inside this folder on macOS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c.

Comment: @BlackArrow like I said, it doesn't apply to MacOS supposedly.

Comment: An excerpt from Peter parker's answer in the aforementioned link:In C++17 there is now an official way to list files of your file system: std::filesystem. There is an excellent answer from Shreevardhan below with this source code:

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path = "/path/to/directory";
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
}

Comment: @Hemil  I saw that, but everytime I put in the path (see above), it doesn't work :/

Comment: I am sorry but I don't have access to a mac. What happens exactly? It doesn't work means? The program does nothing or what? @Universe31

Comment: And can you use C++ 17?

Comment: @Hemil everything that I've found so far is that the c++  17  library isn't available on Xcode and that it uses c++ 11. It gives me  the error that it  can't find the library.

Comment: According to [51288230](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288230/how-to-enable-c17-in-xcode-for-mac-osx) Xcode should support c++17 given the corresponding settings. Give us more information about your enviroment (OS and xcode version, etc.) and the error, what exactly it says.